# rails partial rendering with uniq id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to render a partial on a view when user is pressing a button, so actually it's a list of partials (the same partial is rendered more times) I use cocoon gem to render the partials like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :features do |s| %>
  <%= render 'feature_fields', f: s %>
<% end %>
<div class="f-input for-button to-right">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add more', f, :features, :class => "radius blue button" %>
</div>
```

and in my partial I have this code:

```
<% div_id = DateTime.now.to_i %>
```

so the idea is to have an uniq id for every rendered partial but my problem is the partials renders ok but the id is the same, the first id generated is applied to every partial

Comment: Try with `rand()` instead. Does it still behave the same way?

Comment: no, it's the same, the first id is different but the others are the same, I tried a lot of methods to generate the random number, but it's always the same, I think the problem is in how rails renders this partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using cocoon, using partial counter or any other modification in the partial itself would not help you.
This is because cocoon renders **one** template for new instances and uses this locally in the browser to generate new nested attribute blocks.

You can use cocoons callbacks to modify the generated block with JS.

See the [cocoon readme](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoon#Callbacks__upon_insert_and_remove_of_items_).

Comment: I tried to use link_to_remove_association which should solve my problem because i'm using this id's for removing the generated partials, but link_to_remove_association it's not working, I put it in the partial like this <%= link_to_remove_association('remove this', f, :class => "radius button blue") %> but when I press on it nothing happens, maybe i'm using it wrong?

Comment: this looks OK. It has to be within the <div class="nested-fields"> that is encapsulating the whole partial.