# Give each partial its own id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I am working on an app in Rails that will allow Questions to be added to a Quiz through Link. (a has_many: through association). So far I am implementing this with the Cocoon gem.

The _form.html.erb where Questions are inserted is shown below:

```
<table class = "table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Answers</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id = "question_table">
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="questions">
<div id="questionno"></div>

    <%= f.fields_for :links do |link| %>
    <% render 'link_fields', f: link %>
    <% end %> 
</div>


<div class="links">
    <div id="button_text">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <%= link_to_add_association f, :links, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "tbody#question_table", :"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", :class => "button" do %>Add question<% end %>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each time link_to_add_association is called my _link_fields.html.erb is drawn. This partial contains several fields. A snippet of this file is shown below:

```
<tr class = "table_row" >

<div class="nested-fields link-fields" >
<div id="question_from_list">



    <td class="col-sm-1">   
        <div class = "field">

            <%= f.select :question_category, options_for_select(Category.all.collect { |category|
            [category.categoryBody.titleize, category.id] }, 1), {}, { id: "categories_select_1" } %>
        </div>
    </td>
```

What I would like to do is give each f.select its' own id. I have done some googling and it seems the way to achieve this in cocoon is with callbacks.

I am trying to use the before_insert callback to generate an id and fetch the f.select element and change its id. However this doesn't seem to be working. My code is as follows:

assets/javascripts/quizzes.coffee:

```
$('#questions a.add_fields').data('association-insertion-position', 'before').data 'association-insertion-node', 'this'
$('#questions').on 'cocoon:after-insert', ->
  $(this).children('#categories_select_1').attr 'id', 'newId'
  return
```

This callback doesn't seem to do anything. Other code in my quizzes.coffee file runs absolutely fine so I am sure the file is loaded.

I am sure there is something simple I have overlooked but I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

Any help would be enormously appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails partial rendering with uniq id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420215/rails-partial-rendering-with-uniq-id)

Comment: Just out of curiousity: _why_ do you need this unique id?

Comment: Each partial has a pair of dependent drop downs. So I want to be able to say 'drop down A has changed for this field so change the set of values in drop down B to reflect this'. I have fixed this now I had to change my coffee script to fetch the drop down through all of the nested html elements that it was in.